# temperatures in an atmosphere unaltered by the effect

Tags: phrase-meaning, word-meaning

> Their analysis reveals an unambiguous footprint of human-caused climate change. The team compared the observed heat with maximum daily temperatures predicted by climate models, including simulations of **temperatures in an atmosphere unaltered by the effect** of rising greenhouse-gas concentrations. They concluded that the global average temperature increase of 1.2 °C since pre-industrial times made the extreme heatwave at least 150 times more likely to happen.

Source: [Nature](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-021-01869-0)

In the phrase "temperatures in an atmosphere unaltered by the effect of rising greenhouse-gas concentrations"? What is "unalltered"? "Atmosphere" or "temperatures"? Logically, if greenhouse gas rises, the atmosphere would be altered. So I guess that it is the temperatures is/are unaltered. I am not sure.

Comment: Just for interest, the article quoted may be grammatically correct. But the severity of heat waves has no noticeable upward trend over the last 120 years. Indeed, the IPCC concluded that the sign of the trend was not certain, meaning it could have become less frequent. So the "150 times" result is quite suspect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The atmosphere is unaltered.

The scientists have a model of the current climate, where the atmosphere has been **altered** from its original state by the addition of greenhouse gases. They also have a model of a hypothetical atmosphere that has not been so altered.

They ran simulations on both models to predict maximum daily temperatures, and they found that in the "unaltered atmosphere" model the heatwave was less likely to have happened.